# How do I grab xml from rss feed and convert that to Json object in Android?

Tags: android, json, xml-parsing

I am new to Android. I want to parse RSS feed. I have this feed "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=%27melbourne%27" a weather feed from google. How can I grab the XML data and convert that into Json object that I'll use to populate a listView later on? Or is there any other fast way to parse rss feed in Android? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your best bet is to implement a SAXParser to parse the XML content into an Java object (or a list of Java objetcs). I don't think you need to convert it to JSON if you just want to populate the data into a list view.
for more information about a SAXPArser: Google and stackoverflow search are your friends ;)

Comment: Thank you, so may i know when to use json or saxparser? one of my client told me about json to be fast for garbing news from rss and all.

Comment: using a saxparser is one way to handle xml data. json is a different data format. normally web APIs provide information in xml and/or json format. as an application developer you don't convert between those two, you just parse it into objects